# Display JSON result in table Laravel 5.8

Tags: json, ajax, laravel-5.8

I want to display the JSON results to my HTML table in Laravel 5.8.
The result returned from the controller is as follows.

```
[[{"logged_on":"2019-06-24 00:00:00"},{"logged_on":"2019-06-21 00:00:00"}]]
```

My Ajax success function is as follows:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "get",
      data: {user_id:user_id},
      contentType: "application/json",dataType: "json",
       success: function(data){ // What to do if we succeed
      if(data){
          alert(data);
            var len = data.length;
            var txt = "";
            if(len > 0){
                for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                    if(data[i].logged_on){
                        txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].logged_on;
                    }
                }
                if(txt != ""){
                    $("#table").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                }
            }
        }

else{
    alert("fails");
}
}
    });
```

Below is my controller function

```php
$user_id = $requests->input('user_id');
$data = UserLogins::select('logged_on')->where('user_id',$user_id)->get()->toArray();

return response()->json(array($data));
```

But I am not getting the result in my table.

Comment: The result obtained from $data is already an array remove array from the response and format the result in the view file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user_id = $requests->input('user_id');
$data = UserLogins::select('logged_on')->where('user_id',$user_id)->get()->toArray();

return response()->json($data); // remove array() because $data return array
```